# Custom protocol does't support Identifiable in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, protocols, identifiable

I have defined a `CustomProtocol`, which requires a unique identifier. I have also created a `CustomModel` that implements this protocol. Despite having an id property as required by the `Identifiable` protocol, I am unable to use `CustomModel` as an identifiable type in SwiftUI.

```
protocol CustomProtocol: Identifiable {
    var id: String { get }
}

struct CustomModel: CustomProtocol {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
}

class CustomModelStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [any CustomProtocol] = []
    
    init() {
        models = Array(repeating: CustomModel(), count: 10)
    }
}

struct CustomProtocolView: View {
    
    @StateObject var store = CustomModelStore()
    @State var selectedModel: (any CustomProtocol)?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(store.models) { model in
                Text(model.id)
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedModel = model
                    }
            }
            .sheet(item: $selectedModel) { model in
                Text(model.id)
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomProtocolView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomProtocolView()
    }
}
```

Of course I can specify `id` in `ForEach`, but this way doesn't acceptable for me because I have no chance do it in `.sheet` or `.fullScreenCover` view modifiers. In my store I also can't change type from `CustomProtocol` to `CustomModel`

Comment: "because I have no chance do it in `.sheet` or `.fullScreenCover` view modifiers" Then why did you show `ForEach`? Wouldn't showing an example with `.sheet` better illustrate the problem? Please show some code that *actually* shows where your problem is.

Comment: Remove the variable `id` from `CustomProtocol`: it is not an implementation, but just a protocol; because it conforms to `Identifiable`, `id` is implicitly required, only `CustomModel` needs to implement an `id` variable. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @Sweeper Does it make sense? models should acts like `Identifiable` with confirming custom protocol anywhere, without additional options or logic. Anyway updated example with `.sheet`

Comment: I've noticed that as well, you can work around it by specifying the id explicitly like so: `ForEach(viewModel.models, id: \.id)`.

Comment: SwiftUI requires concrete types there is no way around this

Comment: This really sounds like you want to use `Generics` that conform to your custom protocol, but you can't use a `Protocol` as a `Type`. `Protocols` describe attributes that a `Type` must implement(if any), but they are not in and of themselves a `Type`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard "protocol existentials (`any` types) do not conform to protocols." `selectedModel` does not conform to CustomProtocol (or to Identifiable). Only concrete types conform to protocols.

As Baglan notes, you can deal with the ForEach by passing `id: \.id`, but you'll have to redesign the `.sheet` to not require Identifiable, or you'll need to get rid of the `any CustomProtocol` and use a concrete type.

Exactly how that works depends a lot on exactly what CustomProtocol does and what kinds of objects are in `models`. If they're all the same object (like in your example), then you would generally make CustomModelStore and CustomProtocolView generic:

```
// Make generic over the model
class CustomModelStore<Model: CustomProtocol>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var models: [Model] = []

    // Initialize with the correct type, not hard-coded CustomModel
//    init() {
//        models = Array(repeating: CustomModel(), count: 10)
//    }
}

// Make generic over the model
struct CustomProtocolView<Model: CustomProtocol>: View {

    @StateObject var store = CustomModelStore<Model>()
    @State var selectedModel: Model?

    // Now your original code is fine.
    var body: some View {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you have different types in the array, then it will depend on how all of this really works to design the right solution. Generally the answer is to `.map` the objects to some concrete Model struct that the view uses rather than the underlying objects, but it depends on your problem.